# Spectrum and Unitary Equivalence

Tags: matrices

I am trying to understand why the following implication holds:

If $A$ and $B$ have the same singular values, they are unitarily equivalent (that is, there exist unitary U,V such that $A = UBV$).

Comment: having the same spectrum is evidently an equivalence relation in the set theoretic context. can you find a canonical representative for each equivalence class? if so, consider what change of basis is required to bring each matrix to the canonical form

Comment: What definition of singular values are you using?

Answer (score 2):

$A=U_1\Sigma V_1^*$, $B=U_2\Sigma V_2^*$. Can you manipulate this? What do we know about $U_i$ and $V_i$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent to the same diagonal matrix of singular values.  Now, can you show that unitary equivalence is transitive?

Answer (score 0):

Let A and B be square matrices is the same dimension. Because singular values are uniquely determined, we may write $A=U_1\Sigma V_1^*$ and $B=U_2\Sigma V_2^*$ for the same $\Sigma$. Then $\Sigma=U_1^*A V_1=U_2^*B V_2$, so $A=U_1U_2^*B V_2V_1^*=UBV$ for $U:=U_1U_2^*$, $V:=V_2V_1^*$, noting that the product of two unitary matrices is itself unitary.

Now, typically unitary equivalence (although you specified otherwise, so your claim is correct under the given definition) is defined as $A=QBQ^*$ for unitary $Q$. Under *this* definition, this proof would require that $U_1U_2^*=V_2V_1^*$, which is not true in general; it turns out that actually the claim would be false, even though its converse - unitary equivalence implies having same singular values - is still indeed true and easily shown.